# Default activity transition for fragment

Tags: java, android

How to set default `activity` transition animation for `fragments` in an android app

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.transition.fade_in,R.transition.fade_out);
```

I have `fade_in` and `fade_out` xml but i want to make the `fragment` loaded should like an `activity` in the app ?